# Running the edX Developer Stack: Error on running paver lms

Tags: python, python-2.7, edx

I am following edx tutorial to run devstack(from http://edx-installing-configuring-and-running.readthedocs.org/en/latest/devstack/run_devstack.html#default-accounts-on-devstack) I am getting an error while running command "paver lms" .

Error is as follow :

```
edxapp@precise64:~/edx-platform$ paver devstack lms
---> pavelib.servers.devstack
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_prereqs
---> pavelib.assets.update_assets
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_ruby_prereqs
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_node_prereqs
python manage.py lms --settings=devstack preprocess_assets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    from safe_lxml import defuse_xml_libs
ImportError: No module named safe_lxml

Captured Task Output:
---------------------

---> pavelib.servers.devstack
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_prereqs
---> pavelib.assets.update_assets
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_ruby_prereqs
---> pavelib.prereqs.install_node_prereqs
python manage.py lms --settings=devstack preprocess_assets

Build failed running pavelib.servers.devstack: Subprocess return code: 1
```

Please guide me what needs to be done to run  the command.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Vagrant box? `vagrant halt`, `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh`.

Comment: I have restarted the system many times.. further tried the commands mentioned.. but still same result

Comment: You should post an issue on https://github.com/edx/configuration/issues. These guys know edX more than everyone else.

Comment: Ok thanks... I have posted it but I think they take time to reply...

Comment: I am facing this error but on my local like 'pyton manage.py runserver' when i directly try to run without install any *.txt file under requirement folder

Comment: Are you sure your all *.txt files run successfully on vagrant instance
can u try like 'pip install -r base.txt' and all one by one

Answer (score 2):

You have to run

```
paver install_prereqs
paver update_assets lms --settings=devstack
paver update_assets studio/cms --settings=devstack
```

otherwise install requirements mannually

add following to the file requirements/edx/local.txt and rerun the above commands

```
-e common/lib/capa
-e common/lib/chem
-e common/lib/dogstats
-e common/lib/safe_lxml
-e common/lib/sandbox-packages
-e common/lib/symmath
-e common/lib/xmodule
```

Please refer [paver](http://edx-developer-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pavelib.html)

Comment: where can I find the requirements/edx/local.txt folder?

Comment: located in /opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/requirements/edx/local.txt